# WAG54G2 Configuration

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a problem. I Want to configure my Linksys WAG54G2 annex A router , But I can't configure with the 192.168.1.1 adress beceause it's connected with an ethernet Cable to another router ; So when ever I enter 192.168.1.1 adress it sents me to the configuration page of the router that is connected with the DSL cable. I can't connect my WAG54G2 to the DSL cable because it's stick on a wall . Please can someone give me a solution to configure it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly configure your router you'll have to connect a PC directly to the router (forget about the other DSL modem/router).

- Unplug everything (all routers, and all connections from/to your computer)
- Plug your WAG54G2 router to your computer via an ethernet cable (the normally blue one with a RJ45 connector, like [this](http://www.amazon.com/b?node=464398).
- Turn on your computer. Your router problably has DHCP turned on so you won't need to manually change your computer's ip address. Access 192.168.1.1. You'll now be able to connect to the WAG54G2 router
- Go to the router configuration page and change its IP address to something else, like say 192.168.1.254
- Write it down (stick a label to the router) so you won't forget it later
- Plug everything up again.

Now you'll be able to access your DSL modem/router on 192.168.1.1, and your WAG54G2 router on 192.168.1.254 :)

If you can't connect your computer directly to the WAG54G2 for mechanical reasons, you can do the same procedure but with this "other" router (unplug everything, connect only your PC to this other router, change its IP address to something else, then connect everything up again).

Hope it helps

Comment: I've just connected my PC to the the WAG54G2 with the Ethernet Cable but I couldn't access the 192.168.1.1 :( .. So I'll try to do it with the other router and I'll tell you if it worked or not. By the way thank you very much. It's so kind of you :)

Comment: Ok, try the other router then! If it doesn't work, make sure you're plugging the cable to one of the ETHERNET ports (not the adsl port) of the WAG54G2 router (as instructed in page 4 of the [manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/linksys/wag54g2/manual-265.pdf) (7 of the PDF). If it still doesn't work you might try to RESET your WAG54G2 and try again (page 5, just press the reset button and wait 5 seconds).

Comment: It didn't work :( The other router is accecible at the new address that I gave to it, but my WAG54G2 is not accessible to the 192.168.1.1, I think that it is already changed to a new another address but if it's the case how can I find it ..?

Comment: I've clicked the button reset but the router power and internet signal was orange and the reset stayed for almost 18hours then I unplug the cable and nothing changed :(

Comment: The reset procedure should have reset the address to 192.168.1.1. Try to reset again, reboot PC and then try to reconnect. If it doesn't work, you may try to use the "setup cd" the manual tells about. If it still doesn't work, you may try to manually set your computer's IP address to say 192.168.1.40 and then try to connect. At last try a different PC/Mac and cable/Ethernet port on the router (if you were trying with port 1 try port 2 for instance). If it all fails, you might have a device malfunction.